# Split equation with \begin{split} - brackets don't follow

Tags: equations, amsmath, brackets, split

I have a really long equation, which I want to split into two lines. I searched the internet and found that it works with a split environment. It actually does! But I have big (or automatically sized) brackets which start on the first and end on the second line. But the second line has no closing bracket - it gets lost somewhere.
Could you help me fix it?

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:vanderWaals}
\begin{split}
     V_{vdW} = &-\frac{A}{6}\left[\frac{2r_1r_2}{h^2+2(r_1+r_2)h}
     +\frac{2r_1r_2}{h^2+2(r_1+r_2)h+4r_1r_2}\\
     &+ln\left(\frac{h^2+2(r_1+r_2)h}{h^2+2(r_1+r_2)h+4r_1r_2}\right)\right],
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\left` and `\right` pairs are not allowed to span line breaks in a multi-line displayed equation structure. Your best option is to replace `\left[` with `\biggl[` and to replace `\right]` with `\biggr]`. And, while you're at it, you might also replace `\left(` with `\biggl(` and replace `\right)` with `\biggr)`.

Comment: @Mico, I'm sorry I didn't find the post above. But yes, it is the same problem

Comment: Off-topic: (i) You should  replace `ln` ("natural logarithm", right?) with `\ln`. The backslash character makes `\ln` a macro, which gets expanded to an upright (not math-italic) "ln". (ii) You should definitely replace `= &-` in the first row with `&= -`, to assure that the `-` symbol before `\frac` gets treated as a unary rather than as a binary operator.